# !important not being considered

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am actually trying to make a website mobile friendly. The website is in 2 column layout and I added height to left column (side menu) but it doesn't take precedence.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.landing_container .side_menu{
    width:170px;
    height:300px !important;
}
.landing_container {
    float: none  !important;
    width: 100%  !important;
}
.main_content {
    float: none  !important;
    width: 100%  !important;
}
```

Height doesn't take precedence, in the dev tools it cancels out and height: 4658px; (from element.style) pops up. I see no place in the project defining height for my side menu. Am I missing something ?

P.S
Specificity is exact and width seems to work with no issues.

Post Edit:
I am sorry for semi-colon issue.
I had not copy pasted but was rather writing that in a hurry. I do have those semi-colons in proper place. This should be something else.

Comment: Remove the `;` between the value and the !important.  This is a typo

Comment: Hi Tarak. There shouldn't be a semicolon ; in the middle of the statement. So you should change the following: height:300px; !important; to the following: height:300px !important;

Comment: this is simply a css/html issue - why the `php`,`javascript` tags?

Comment: You might need to provide more context. If it's not a syntax error, it's hard for anyone to give constructive feedback. What you've provided looks perfectly valid. We'd need to see the HTML structure and the rest of the CSS. If it's just the `.side_menu` class you're having trouble with could you provide all CSS & media queries relating to that.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to avoid `!important` if you can. It adds complexity, especially if your specificity is exact already. But if you must you must.

It looks like you have a syntax error. Remove the first semicolon.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .landing_container .side_menu{
     width:170px;
     height:300px !important;
  }
  .landing_container {
     float: none !important;
     width: 100% !important;
  }
  .main_content {
     float: none !important;
     width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the post but thanks for the heads up. I wasn't sure why height is being canceled out that's the exact reason for using important.